# Script to add SPFx webpart to a classic page using PnP Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework

I have to run a Powershell script that creates a Site Collection App catalog , then add an SPFx webpart to it and publish it. Also it has to install it in the site. I have done upto this part.

Last piece missing is to add it to a classic page. I can see adding to modern pages. but i need to add it to a classic page. I have seen this post - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Developer/PnP-PowerShell-Adding-SPFx-web-part-to-a...

But it has a step to manually add SPFx app to a classic page and to get the XML. This is not possible in my case as I have to automate everything. Is there way to achieve my need or to tweak the method provided in the post.

As far my code is:

```
Add-PnPSiteCollectionAppCatalog -Site $url

Add-PnPApp -Path D:/custom.sppkg -Scope Site -Publish

Install-PnPApp -Identity "custom-webpart" -Scope Site
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can follow the below mentioned steps and after that you will be able to add your webpart to a classic page.

1) Go to your SharePoint workbench page (`i.e https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx`)

2) Add your SPFx webpart on the page and configure it as per your requirements.

3) Once done, you can export your webpart data by clicking on `Webpart Data` tab as below:

[image]

4) In the dialog, you will find the classic pages tab. Click on it, which will open the webpart's xml as below:

[image]

5) Copy the entire data, i.e whole section including the `<webParts>...</webparts>` tag.

6) In your local file system, create a `yourWebpart.dwp` or `yourWebpart.xml` file and paste that data inside this file and save your file.

7) After that, you can run the below PS commands:

```
$webpartXML = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\yourWebpart.dwp")

Add-PnPWebPartToWebPartPage -ServerRelativePageUrl "/sites/test/Pages/classicPage.aspx" -Xml $webpartXML -ZoneId "Custom Zone" -ZoneIndex 0
```

Result would be something like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply and your time in explaining this. By seeing this, i hope this should work for me. I will try and will let you know on this.

Comment: @CHANDRUD did it work?

Comment: Yeah It worked.